# What exactly is this block of JQuery doing?

Tags: jquery

Could someone explain this line by line?

```
     $(function() {
 $('.js-nav a, .js-connect').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
 $('body, html').animate({
  scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
}, 750);
```

});
});

Comment: Go through the specific methods in the jQuery api...will give you a pretty good idea by doing that. Doing basic research like that is expected before asking questions

Answer (score 0):

On click on the `.js-nav a` link, the page will scroll to the position of `$.attr(this, 'href')` which is the link target I guess.